# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined, even though already binded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to print a state in my `reactjs` web page, i already bind the function just like the other answer says but it still gave me the same error, here is my code

```
export class Tambah extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
  }

  add(event){
    this.setState({company: event.target.value})
  }
}

function FormTambah(){
  return(
    <div className="konten container-sm">
    <br></br><br></br>
    <div className="tabel card rounded">
      <div className="card-body">
      <p className="head panel-body">Add User</p>
      <br/><br/>
      <form>
        <p>Email*</p>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.company} onChange={this.add} className="email form-control col-sm-6"/>
        <br/>
        <p>Full Name*</p>
        <input type="text" className="email form-control col-sm-7" placeholder="Enter Fullname" onChange={this.FullName}></input>
        <br/>
        <div className="stat custom-control custom-switch">
          <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input switch-lg" id="customSwitch1"/>
          <label className="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Active Status</label>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" className="submit btn col-sm-1">Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

the error happens right here :

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.company} onChange={this.add} className="email form-control col-sm-6"/>
```

i already bind the `add` method after i saw the other question but it still gave me the same error, thanks before, any help will be appreciated

Comment: `FormTambah` is not the same as `Tambah`,  there `this` is going to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state` is available in class components not function components.

also beside react, what you're doing is not legal in JS, you're defining state in one class and try to use it in a different function that is not belong to that class.

what you want to do is move the code in `FormTambah` function to `render` function in the class component

```
export class Tambah extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
  }

  add(event){
    this.setState({company: event.target.value})
  }

  render(){
  return(
    <div className="konten container-sm">
    <br></br><br></br>
    <div className="tabel card rounded">
      <div className="card-body">
      <p className="head panel-body">Add User</p>
      <br/><br/>
      <form>
        <p>Email*</p>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.company} onChange={this.add} className="email form-control col-sm-6"/>
        <br/>
        <p>Full Name*</p>
        <input type="text" className="email form-control col-sm-7" placeholder="Enter Fullname" onChange={this.FullName}></input>
        <br/>
        <div className="stat custom-control custom-switch">
          <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input switch-lg" id="customSwitch1"/>
          <label className="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Active Status</label>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" className="submit btn col-sm-1">Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `FormTambah` into `render`:

```
export class Tambah extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    }

    add(event) {
        this.setState({ company: event.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="konten container-sm">
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <div className="tabel card rounded">
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <p className="head panel-body">Add User</p>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <form>
                            <p>Email*</p>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                value={this.state.company}
                                onChange={this.add}
                                className="email form-control col-sm-6"
                            />
                            <br />
                            <p>Full Name*</p>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="email form-control col-sm-7"
                                placeholder="Enter Fullname"
                                onChange={this.FullName}
                            ></input>
                            <br />
                            <div className="stat custom-control custom-switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input switch-lg" id="customSwitch1" />
                                <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customSwitch1">
                                    Active Status
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <button type="submit" className="submit btn col-sm-1">
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```